# An Algebra of Sets Generated by Multiple of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $\mathcal{M}=\{m\mathbb{N} \ : \ m\in\mathbb{N} \},$ and consider the algebra $a(\mathcal{M})$ generated by $\mathcal{M}$. This means that $a(\mathcal{M})$ is the smallest algebra that contains $\mathcal{M}$.
>
> What is an explicit representation of $a(\mathcal{M})$?

I need this for another problem I am working on.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the least element of $\Bbb N,$ for you? (It probably won't make a difference, but just in case....)

Comment: I believe for this problem it is $1$.

Comment: Gotcha. This isn't a complete solution, but note that if we put $$\mathscr P:=\{p^k\Bbb N\mid k,p\in\Bbb N,p\text{ is prime}\},$$ then the algebra generated by $\mathscr P$ is identical to that generated by $\mathcal M$. This is because for coprime $m,n\in\Bbb N,$ we have $$mn\Bbb N=m\Bbb N\cap n\Bbb N,$$ and if $m\mid n,$ then $m\Bbb N\supseteq n\Bbb N$ (with the inclusion strict if $m\ne n$).

Comment: Also, I *believe* (though I'm not sure) that no proper subset of $\mathscr P$ can generate the algebra in question.

Comment: I think you might be right, I don't know what my professor was looking for specifically here.

Comment: Well, "explicit representation "suggests an answer like: "The algebra in question consists of all subsets of $\Bbb N$ of one of the following forms: [list of forms]."

Comment: Can you think of a way to write every set in the algebra in terms of finite disjoint unions? If that was possible it would solve the problem I need this for.

Comment: I don't know about finite disjoint unions, but I'm working on finding an explicit representation. What can I say? The problem intrigues me.